# CreateProcessWithLogonW Exit Code

Tags: c#, winapi, vbscript, impersonation, wsh

I am trying to capture the exit code of a process created through CreateProcessWithLogonW. The process being started is wscript since I am running a VBScript file. I am using this API call b/c of the need to have the current user impersonating a service account. When I attempt to capture the exit code the script returns, I am getting an access denied error which I believe is due to the fact the process was created under the service account. I attempted to impersonate the user before trying to capture the exit code but that failed as well with a duplicate token error. Does anyone know how to properly capture the exit code in this specific situation? I cannot use Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() as this does not give me the exit code that the script returns when it fails or succeeds. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    public static Process_Info Run_Command_As(String str_Command, String str_Working_Directory,
    String str_Domain, String str_Name, String str_Password)
{
    // DECLARE VARIABLES
    Process_Info pi_Process_Info = new Process_Info();
    Startup_Info si_Start_Info = new Startup_Info();  

    // CREATE PROCESS
    si_Start_Info.i_CB = Marshal.SizeOf(si_Start_Info);

    try
    {
    // GET RESULT OF PROCESS CREATION
    Boolean b_Result = CreateProcessWithLogonW(
        str_Name,
        str_Domain,
        str_Password,
        0,
        null,
        str_Command,
        0,
        IntPtr.Zero,
        str_Working_Directory,
        ref si_Start_Info,
        out pi_Process_Info
    );

    // CHECK IF NOT CREATED SUCCESSFULLY
    if (!b_Result)
    {
        // THROW EXCEPTION
        throw new Exception(String.Format("CreateProcessWithLogonW Error #{0}",
        Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
    }
    }
    catch(Exception Ex)
    {
    // CLOSE HANDLES
    CloseHandle(pi_Process_Info.ip_Process);
    CloseHandle(pi_Process_Info.ip_Thread);
    }

    return pi_Process_Info;
}

/ CALL TO CREATE NEW PROCESS INFO OBJECT AND SET EXECUTABLE INFO OBJECT
Process_Info Process_Info = Run_Command_As(String.Format("wscript.exe {0}",
    Path.Combine(Server_Info.Server, Executable_Info.Location, Command)), Path.Combine(Server_Info.Server, Executable_Info.Location),
    Credential.Domain, Credential.Username, Credential.Password);

// GET PROCESS BY ID
Process Proc = Process.GetProcessById(Process_Info.i_Process_ID);
if (!Proc.HasExited) { Proc.WaitForExit(); }
Int32 i_Exit_code = Proc.ExitCode;
```

Comment: Do you want us to write the entire code for you?

Comment: No, I would rather be pointed in the right direction so that I can look it up and learn

Comment: Well, that's going to be a little tricky because you described what you did rather than showed the code. A nice [mcve] would help.

Comment: The GetExitCodeProcess API function should work, if passed the process handle returned by CreateProcessWithLogonW.  If that's what you're doing, you're doing it wrong, and we won't be able to help until you post the code.  (Except for one thought: are you sure that the script isn't returning an access denied error?)

Comment: Code has been added and the line that throws the Access Denied is "Int32 i_Exit_code = Proc.ExitCode;".

@Harry Johnston, the GetExitCodeProcess API call is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I am now getting the exit code of the impersonated user.

Comment: Glad that helped.  I though this question might be a duplicate, but I can't find one applicable to C#.  Perhaps you could post your own answer, showing how to P/Invoke GetExitCodeProcess?